# CiviMobile: Can't log into CiviCRM using CiviMobile

Tags: extension

I installed:

- CiviMobile extension in CiviCRM;
- CiviMobile app on Android.

When I try to login using mobile browser, CiviCRM works. Loging in with same credentials in CiviMobile app does not work, it says: Sorry. We were not able connecting your CiviCRM server.

Logging into the demo server works.

Comment: Does not work for me either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There could be few reasons:
1. Please check the correct extension is installed. You need to install *CiviMobileAPI* extension (https://civicrm.org/extensions/civimobileapi), not CiviMobile. You can find installation steps here https://civimobile.agiliway.com/#how-to-start.

2. What CMS do you use?

   - If you use Drupal or Joomla then there should be no problem. Please check that you specify proper URL paying attention to http/https and www or without www.
   - if you use WP then there is a bug in core CiviCRM API which prevents API works correctly. Please start reading here for more details https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12813#issuecomment-428152827
     As an immediate solution, we are preparing API fix patch WP clients. It will include our quick fix and instruction how to install in. 
     Please write us at civicrm@agiliway.com IF you use WP.

If it still does not work then please write us (civicrm@agiliway.com) so we can investigate the problem.

Thank you,
 Sergiy

Comment: Sergiy's answer is correct. The issue that causes the problem is that there is already an extension available through the CiviCRM extensions interface called CiviMobile. So I installed that and obviously it didn't work with Agilway's extension. Following Sergiy's advice the extension works perfectly.

Comment: Regarding WordPress. I provided the API patch in [another thread](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/27283/5475)

Comment: Absolutely, the confusion was due to two different extensions with similar names.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Drupal - but after updating the extension and the app to the latest version 4.1.1 the app works like a dream :-)