# CiviMail error: "Sorry an error occurred and your information was not saved"

Tags: wordpress, civimail, mosaico

CiviCRM 5.6.1, WordPress 4.9.8, PHP 7.1.22, MySQL 5.7.23, WordFence 7.1.16

I just started getting this error when trying to create a mailing. It happens with Mosaico and traditional mailings. I previously saw this issue when first using the WordFence security plugin and found a discussion here suggesting to disable WordFence's XSS check, which I did with success until now. That was months ago. The option is still disabled and I even tried disabling WordFence entirely, but no luck. I haven't made any significant changes recently that I can think of. I had no problems with my last weekly mailing.

I also checked with my hosting provider to see if they had made any mod_security rules changes. They hadn't. I don't see anything interesting in the logs. Any ideas?

Comment: I am also seeing this error on my personal dev box. It's just a linux box in my closet, not hosted. It has basically the same configuration, minus the WordFence plugin.

Answer (score 5):

I have seen this error occur on WordPress due to a false positive generated in WordFence security plugin.

If that might be your issue, put WordFence Firewall back into "Learning Mode", try saving/testing a Mosaico template email again in Civi and - if that is the problem - then WordFence should Whitelist the action, and the error should disappear.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Helped me too, though a colleague later said " just try saving the mailing then go into wordfence find the relevant request and whitelist it. That way you are not disabling the functionality while it learns."

Comment: There are some more detail instructions here: https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues/230#issuecomment-366775357

Answer (score 4):

I've run into this error for three reasons:

1: I copied and pasted in text and there was a special character in there that CiviCRM did not like. I figured out which one it was by pasting in only pieces of the text and watching to see when it quit saving and instead gave me the error.

2: I'd upgraded CiviCRM and the permissions weren't correct on some files (I'm logged in as root and therefore have to change owner/group when I upload).

3: A modsecurity issue. My host was able to look at the logs and whitelist the URI that was causing the issue. Last time it was: /civicrm/ajax/rest

Comment: Aha! This definitely helped....

I was failing with new, blank (no template) mailings, so I didn't think it could be #1. 

I hadn't upgraded since my most recent successful mailing, so I didn't think it could be #2. 

My dev box doesn't use mod_security, so I didn't think it was #3, but your mention of "/civicrm/ajax/rest" reminded me that I had applied a small patch for REST.php that was provided by the developers of CiviMobileAPI as a proposed fix for a login issue on WordPress. I offered to test it a few days ago and I apparently forgot to revert! That was it. Thanks!

Comment: Yay! Glad to hear that I at least got your mind thinking in the right direction. Sometimes that's all it takes. :D

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue too and the solution was a twist on Jenni Simonis's [answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/27205/75) so I'll elaborate in case anyone else runs into it.

The specific thing that fixed it for me was granting user & group execute permissions on the wordpress file wp-admin/admin.php.

I was getting a 403 forbidden error in the JS console on this file any time CiviCRM tried to take some kind of ajax action because it was trying to post to /civicrm/ajax/rest through admin.php but didn't have the right permissions.

Comment: Welcome to CiviCRM.SE. The number next to a question or answer does not indicate its sequence, but the number of votes it has received; I have altered the reference in your post as a result. This is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, and if you are new to Stack Exchange, I would strongly recommend you take the site [tour] and review the [help].

Comment: thanks @choster :)

Comment: I still have this issue on WordPress the error I'm getting in the chrome console is "POST https://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/ajax/rest 500"jquery.min.js?r=p6mna:4 
Anyone know what this can be? or how to fix it?